# Where do silverfish blocks spawn in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm in a survival world with a lot of mountains which makes me nervous because  I'm not sure which biome silverfish blocks spawn.

Comment: An easy way to tell which stone blocks are infested with silverfish is by the time it takes to break the block; a silverfish infested stone block can take longer than usual for a pickaxe to break, but can be very quick to break with any other item or barehanded. This means that if a stone is breaking unusually fast when punching it with your hands, then you've found an infested block.

Comment: Thankyou! This is my first successful question!

Answer (score 1):

Blocks infested with silverfish only spawn in the extreme hills. They do not spawn naturally in the strongholds, this may be a misconception because silverfish spawned via the spawner may go into a block, which means they can be found there.

Answer (score 1):

Infested Stone (Stone containing silverfish) spawn in extreme mountain biomes.